# Question on proof that insertions in a distributive category are monos.

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, category-theory

I am studying fibrations, and am dotting i's and crossing t's. I know the following facts are true from the general theory, but I want to do the proofs from scratch because I feel like I learn more that way. There are several posts on this site regarding this topic but they do not address my questions :

let $B$ be a distributive category, so that in particular there is is a canonical isomorphism $\Phi:X\times X+X\times Y\to (X+ Y)\times X.$ There is also an arrow $f:X\times X\to (X+ Y)\times X$ such that $\Phi\circ i_{X\times X}=f,$ which I want to show is a split monomorphism. Therefore, using the following commutative diagram,

$$\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\la}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xleftarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
X & \la{\pi_1} & X\times X & \ra{\pi_2} & X \\
\da{i_x} & & \da{f} & & \da{1_X} & & \ \\
X+Y & \la {p_1} & (X+Y)\times X & \ra{p_2} & X & \\
\end{array}$$

and the diagonal morphism $\delta: X\to X\times X,$ I showed this by exhibiting the retraction $\delta\circ p_2\circ \Phi\circ i_{X\times X} .$

But I never used the fact that $\Phi$ is an $isomorphism.$ The fact that there exists such an arrow was enough. Is this correct?

Now, I need to show that $i_x:X\to X\times Y$ is a monomorphism. So let $i_x\circ f=i_x\circ g.$  Then the result follows from the fact that $\Phi$ is a split mono, and a diagram chase, because if we consider

$$\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\la}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xleftarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
X & \la{g} & Z & \ra{f} & X \\
\da{1_X} & & \da{\phi} & & \da{1_X} & & \ \\
X & \la {\pi_1} & X\times X & \ra{\pi_2} & X & \\
\end{array}$$

and

$$\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\la}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xleftarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
X & \la{f} & Z & \ra{f} & X \\
\da{1_X} & & \da{\psi} & & \da{1_X} & & \ \\
X & \la {\pi_1} & X\times X & \ra{\pi_2} & X & \\
\end{array}$$

then it follows that

$$p_1\circ\Phi\circ \phi=i_X\circ g=i_X\circ f\\ p_2\circ\Phi\circ \phi=f\\ p_1\circ\Phi\circ \psi=i_X\circ f\\ p_2\circ\Phi\circ \psi=f$$

which means that $\Phi\circ \phi=\Phi\circ \psi\Rightarrow \phi=\psi.$

Again, no use of the fact that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism, which leads me to think I have made a mistake.